# Whats a word for someone who thinks everything is easy?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, american-english

I saw this word on a reddit post but I can't find that post no more but its describes a person who thinks everything is easy, and is very douchy. When you ask them a question, they'll be like, "oh thats easy" and then tries to give the most sophisticated answer possible.

Comment: The fashionable word is 'arrogant.' Especially OTT 'incredibly arrogant.'

Comment: These folk tend to think themselves very *eclectic*. But in fact are not.

Comment: A person who is **cocky** is overconfident. He would consider every question as an easy one.

Answer (score 1):

Some words which you may be looking for (in order of their rank):

> 1. ***smart-arse*** = someone who is always trying to seem more clever than other people in a way that is annoying
> 2. ***egomaniac*** = someone who considers themselves to be very important and able to do anything that they want
> 3. ***smart-alec*** = someone who tries to appear clever or who answers questions in a clever way that annoys other people
> 4. ***egotistic*** = considering yourself to be better or more important than other people
> 5. ***know-all*** = a person who thinks that they know much more than other people

Reference: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/)

Apologies for providing the words and their meanings from a British English dictionary even after seeing your American English tag.